# Calculate the Jacobian of a particular diffeomorphism of parallelizable manifold onto itself

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, manifolds, jacobians, geodesics

Let $M$ be $d$-dimensional [parallelizable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelizable_manifold) manifold. Let $e_k(x)$ for $k=1, \dots , d$ be the smooth vector fields forming orthonormal basis in tangent bundle of , these vector fields exist because of parallelizability of the manifold.

Consider mapping
$$ \phi (x)= \gamma_{x, \sqrt{d}e_k}(t)$$
where $\gamma_{x,v}(t)$ denotes the point which moved for time $t$ through the geodesics starting at time 0 at the point $x \in M$ with initial velocity $v \in T_xM$.

Please help me to calculate the Jacobian of $\phi$.Thank you very much!